# I want to build a .net core project on Windows

Tags: c#, .net, bash, msbuild

I want to build a finished c# project on Windows

Can anyone please let me know where to start from.
And should I use bash scripting for this?

Comment: Do you have a finished project that you want to build, or do you want to create a project?

Comment: I have a finished project @HZSudio

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-specific-targets-in-solutions-by-using-msbuild-exe?view=vs-2017

Comment: thanks, I have used msbuild to Clean the project and it is working fine, but when i am using my bash shell to write the script msbuild is not working. @HZStudio

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by this

Comment: Visual Studio is not an option for some reason ? Is there any reason why not no use VS ?

Answer (score 1):

If you [install the .NET Core SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download), you can run `dotnet build` from the commandline in your project directory to build your project.

For more info see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build